# Automate adding NuGet to multiple solutions at once

Tags: nuget

I'm working across a fairly large code base and I'd like to automate the following related tasks of making NuGet available across a number of solutions:

1. Add a .nuget folder (with nuget.exe, nuget.targets, nuget.config) in multiple folders across the source tree
2. In each of the folders from #1, adding the appropriate configuration into the solution file contained in each of the folders

```
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = ".nuget", ".nuget", "{F3BA244B-3E6B-4A37-B0C0-B490885DED86}"
        ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        .nuget\NuGet.Config = .nuget\NuGet.Config
        .nuget\NuGet.exe = .nuget\NuGet.exe
        .nuget\NuGet.targets = .nuget\NuGet.targets
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

Another question (out of curiousity) - We've manually added NuGet into a couple of solutions, and I've noticed that the first GUID is the same across each of these solutions, but the second GUID seems to be different from one solution to the next - does it have to be a different GUID in each solution, or can the same GUID be present across all solutions?

Comment: you really don't want nuget.targets in there, or nuget.exe for that matter. It's a built in feature of Visual Studio and TFS now. Here's docs about the new workflow http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question about GUID: the first GUID indicates the type of the project, while the second GUID is used to identify the project, which is why the first GUID is the same, but the second one is different. For a list of project type GUIDs, see http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx.